# Necessary and sufficient conditions of feature redundancy

Tags: feature-selection

What is the necessary and sufficient conditions of feature redundancy?

If two features have strong correlation, than one of them is redundant feature. Is it true? Provide an example, if it isn't true.

Comment: This depends on what you mean by strong.

Comment: Also depends on what you mean by redundant.